# Reverse a string in c using recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion

So, I want to ask the user to type a word and then, the program will reverse it. This is my code, but it doesn't properly run. What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char anadr(int, int, char pin[]);

main()
{
      char pin[100];
      int l;
      int i=0;
      char res;
      printf("Give word: ");
      scanf("%s", pin);
      l=strlen(pin);
      res=anadr(i,l,pin);
      system("pause");
}

char anadr(int i, int l, char pin[])
{
     if(i<l)
        anadr(i++,l,pin);
     printf("%c", pin[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  I also suggest `return 0` in your `main`.

Comment: Also your anadr function should be void instead of charas it doesn't return anything.

Comment: The program crushes. If I guess right, the prob is there:

 if(i<l)
        anadr(i++,l,pin);

Comment: You are right. I adjusted it from char to void but still nothing.

Comment: This code also won't reverse the string. It will, however, fail nicely in *printing* the string in reverse. So what is it you *really* are trying to do? Print it reversed? Reverse it? Both?

Comment: Well I want it to print it reversed. I've got my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
void anadr(int l, char pin[])
{
     if(l == 0)
          return;

     printf("%c", pin[l - 1]);
     anadr(l - 1, pin);
}

anadr(5, "abcde");
```

Comment: @NorTee Please accept if you found useful.

Answer (score 1):

All your code seems to be trying to do is print the string in reverse. Just recurse to the terminator and dump chars on the way back out.

```
void anadr(const char *p)
{
    if (!*p)
        return;
    anadr(p+1);
    putchar(*p); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is here:

```
if(i<l)
    anadr(i++,l,pin);
```

This causes endless recursion, since `i++` increments `i` only *after* its current value has been passed as argument. Try replacing `i++` with `i + 1`.

Also, the comparison causes an extra call to be made even with the above fix; the character at `pin[l]` is the terminating NUL, which you almost certainly don't want to print. So the comparison should be `if (i+1 < l)`.

Comment: Yes. It works fine. But, why isn't the ++i work the same as the i+1?

Comment: @NorTee `i++` evaluates to the value of `i` _before_ incrementing it by one. `++i` would indeed work for the recursion since that evaluates to the value of `i` _after_ incrementing. But either of these is wrong, because both `++i` and `i++` _change_ the value of `i`, and the following line (`printf("%c", pin[i])`) only works correctly if the value of `i` has not been changed…

Comment: An alternative that would work is `if (++i < l) anadr(i,l,pin); printf("%c", pin[i-1]);` (except none of these work correctly if `l` is 0; then you shouldn't print anything). (By the way, if you found this helpful, please upvote the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You have an off by one error and you should not be using ++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void anadr(int, int, char pin[]);

int main()
{
      char pin[100];
      int l;
      int i=0;
      //char res;
      printf("Give word: ");
      scanf("%s", pin);
      l=strlen(pin);
      anadr(i,l,pin);
      //system("pause");
}

void anadr(int i, int l, char pin[])
{
     if(i<l-1)
        anadr(i+1,l,pin);
     printf("%c", pin[i]);
}
```